# How do I lock FileVault on logout?

Tags: filevault, macos

I want to lock FileVault when I logout. I have two accounts on my Mac one admin and a standard user, only the admin account can open the FileVault. How do I lock FileVault so I need to unlock the FileVault when I logout of any of the two accounts?

As of now I only need to open the FileVault when I have restarted the computer. I use macOS Sierra public beta.

Comment: You don't. If you're already logged in, you've already unlocked FileVault.

Comment: I want to lock FileVault. @IronCraftMan

Comment: What is your target purpose? Do you want FileVault to ask you your password before beginning any new session? Or do you want to be sure that nothing is accessible in clear on your Mac once any session is terminated?

Comment: @klanomath: I liked your version.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Lets say that I close the lid on my MacBook, and if I haven't opened it after a certain time (let's say 60 min) I want the system to lock FileVault. So if I go to bed I want to wake up to the FileVault promt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a non-graphical setting you can try:

```
sudo pmset -a destroyfvkeyonstandby 1
```

That would mean that you need to re-authenticate after sleep transitions to standby. It isn't something that changes at logout, but it's the closest I think you can get at present.

Comment: If I understood right this storing in NVRAM of the FileVault key will just force the session manager to ask it, but the disk is unencrypted mounted.

Comment: @danielAzuelos You are correct - that's the closest I know how to get if you don't restart the Mac (or power it down).